# how to pick up a small draggable sprite stacked on a larger one which is also draggable in andengine

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, touch, sprite, andengine

I've got a problem with my app. I have stacked some sprites of different dimensions (their texture regions are also of different dimensions)

If I drop a small sprite on a bigger one, it all seems to work fine (the small sprite is clearly above the bigger one). If I want to pick up again the small sprite, when I touch it, I always end up dragging the bigger sprite, even if it's level is in a lower level than the smaller sprite's level.

How can I fix this?

I already tried to set to the smaller sprite a region dimension as big as the bigger sprite's, but it didn't work.

Just to be clear, here are two screenshots:

The red "E" is the sprite I moved on the blue "coma". The coma is smaller so when I touch the "E" I moved it correctly:

[image: si]

In this second case, the blue "D" is bigger than the "E" so when I touch it I move a "D" and not the "E"

[image: si]

**EDIT**

Here is how I create my sprites, all stored in a vector:

```
public Vector<Sprite> initSprite(Vector<TextureRegion> tRegionV, final Scene se, Context c){
    Vector<Sprite> aux = new Vector<Sprite>();
    vRes.posizioni = vRes.init();
    
    
    for(int i=0; i<dataV.size(); i++ ){         
        final int gap = dataV.elementAt(i).gap+data[3];  //creo qui la differenza per il dito
        final float sX = dataV.elementAt(i).x;
        final float sY = dataV.elementAt(i).y;;
        final String label = dataV.elementAt(i).label;
        final Context co = c;
        
        sprite = new Sprite(dataV.elementAt(i).x, dataV.elementAt(i).y, tRegionV.elementAt(i))
        
        // gestione del drag & drop
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                    
                    

                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
                    //TOCCO DELLO SPRITE
                    
                    moved=false;
                    
                    startY=getY();
                    startX=getX();
                    
                    if(this.getParent()!=se.getChild(3) && this.getParent()==se.getChild(1)){
                        
                        
                        ChangeLayer(se, this, 1, 3);
                    }
                    else if(this.getParent()!=se.getChild(3) && this.getParent()==se.getChild(2)){
                        
                        
                        ChangeLayer(se, this, 2, 3);
                    }
                             
              
                    
                    MoveYModifier mod = new MoveYModifier(0.1f, getY(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()- gap);
                    this.registerEntityModifier(mod);
                }
                
                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()){
                    //MOVIMENTO DELLO SPRITE
                    moved=true;
                    setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY()
                        - gap /*this.getHeight() / 2*/);
                }

                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
                    //RILASCIO DELLO SPRITE
                    
                    float x =getX() + (getWidth()/2);
                    float y =getY() + (getHeight()/2);
                    
                    if(y<=285){
                    
                        if(y>(sY+ getHeight()/2)-20 && y<(sY+ getHeight()/2)+20 && x>(sX+ getWidth()/2)-20 && x<(sX+ getWidth()/2)+20){
                            
                            if(this.getParent()!=se.getChild(1) && this.getParent()==se.getChild(2)){
                                ChangeLayer(se, this, 2, 1);

                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        
                        else {
                            val=vRes.fallInCell(x,y,this.getHeight(),label);
                            setPosition(val[0]-(this.getWidth()/2),val[1]-(this.getHeight()/2)+6);
                        }
                    }
                    // if che se ho solo toccato e si è alzata, deve tornare dove stava
                    if(moved==false){
                        MoveYModifier mod = new MoveYModifier(0.1f, getY(), startY);
                        this.registerEntityModifier(mod);
                        setPosition(startX, startY);
                    }
                    
                    if(this.getParent()!=se.getChild(1) && this.getParent()==se.getChild(3)){
                        
                        ChangeLayer(se, this, 3, 1);
                    }
                    else if(this.getParent()!=se.getChild(1) && this.getParent()==se.getChild(2)){
                        
                        ChangeLayer(se, this, 2, 1);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        
        aux.addElement(sprite);
    }
    
    return aux;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort z ordering of sprites to tell which one is on top

ie 'd' z order is 1
'e' z order is 0

'e' z order is lower than 'd' so you know its on the bottom

on the first object (object N)creation, the initial z order is 0 for that object(object N)

for each additional object (object N) 
when created check

```
 if (Object N) intersects with a previous object (object N-1).
     (object N).z-order = (object N-1).z-order+1,
```

(there will be additional checks needed if you plan on having many object overlapping)

so when a user touches check if the touch location intersects with an object(s)
if more than one intersection occurs use the highest z order object

Comment: and how can i determine "ok this is the on top sprite, move this istead of the lower?"

Comment: without seeing you code I have no idea how your creating objects or positioning them or anything but the order should be set when the sprite object is first created and then updated whenever they are dropped. i'll edit my answer with a rough outline.

Comment: i've add th code for the sprite declaration and the relative onAreaTouched. i've followed the andengine drag and drop tutorial